# ¿Cómo mostrar todos los registros usando WHERE en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select count(A.usuario) as Total, B.cec, C.cec_descri, D.cec, D.nombrecec, D.estado, D.numPin, D.coorX, D.coorY, D.activo 
from accesos A 
inner join emp B on A.usuario = B.emp
inner join cec C on B.cec = C.cec 
inner join centrosacceso D on C.cec = D.cec
group by B.cec, C.cec_descri, D.cec, D.nombrecec, D.cec, D.nombrecec, D.estado, D.numPin, D.coorX, D.coorY, D.activo
```

Donde mi resultado es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero debo de establecer una condición Where con ayuda de un campo llamada Fecha_acceso, que se encuentra en la tabla "accesos A", Este Where hara que el campo total me traiga los registros que esten en una fecha determinada.

Ejemplo:

```
select count(A.usuario) as Total, B.cec, C.cec_descri, D.cec, D.nombrecec, D.estado, D.numPin, D.coorX, D.coorY, D.activo 
from accesos A 
inner join emp B on A.usuario = B.emp
inner join cec C on B.cec = C.cec 
inner join centrosacceso D on C.cec = D.cec
where 
A.fecha_acceso = '20200221 10:40:00'
group by B.cec, C.cec_descri, D.cec, D.nombrecec, D.cec, D.nombrecec, D.estado, D.numPin, D.coorX, D.coorY, D.activo
```

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el campo Total, me da el numero 2, esta bien ya que el campo cuenta las personas que se conectaron a tal día a tal hora.
Pero lo que quiero es mostrar todos los registros como la primer imagen, pero usando WHERE con la misma condición de la fecha, para que en el campo Total me aparezcan los accesos de todos y si no han tenido acceso, que aparezca un 0

Ejemplo de como seria el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado unir, SELECTS pero no me ha dado resultados. Alguna idea? Se los agradezco por adelantado.

Comment: habria que ver tus datos de origen, pero si agregas ese where a la primer tabla, solo se van a ver los registros que cumplan ese where... si los otros no tienen nada en esas fechas, no se van a agregar....

Comment: Entonces no es posible realizar esto?

Comment: Me parece que lo que necesitas es `LEFT JOIN`, o bien usar sub-consultas. Sea como sea, [conviene que nos muestres un fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) con un pequeño set de datos de ejemplo y lo que estás intentando. Eso es más importante que perderse en explicaciones y capturas de pantalla que no siempre ayudan a entender el problema.

Comment: No es que no se puede.. con tu explicacion, no parece posible... necesitamos un ejemplo claro, como te pide Cedano, para poder ayudarte...